# Regex without spaces

Tags: angularjs, regex, validation, typescript

I have to prepare regular expression pattern where:

- only alphanumeric values, without whitespaces

Right now I have this:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/
```

But it is not work, because when I use f.e. `<one or more spaces>asdasdasdas` it is not recognized as not correct. Same situation when I insert `asdasdasdads<one or more spaces>`. I have to exclude space on begin and at end of my string.

Comment: Since your regex does not allow whitespace, the only possible problem is that you do not use `ng-trim="false"`. Add it, and the problem should be solved.

Comment: Checked your regular expression at regex101 and it looks correct.